# Using Azure DevOps API to get Work Item Types Field values for a field that has dynamic data based on the value of another field

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using the API query

> GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}/fields/{field}?api-version=5.1

with great success to get all of the allowed values for my fields. The issue is that the options to one of my dropdown menus is populated based on the selected value of another dropdown menu. Is it possible to pass a value to this GET query and then retrieve all of the allowedValues for this dynamically populated menu?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is currently impossible to pass a value to this GET query and then retrieve all of the `allowedValues` for this dynamically populated menu.

`Work Item Types Field-Get` rest api should only get the `allowedValues` of a specified field, cannot implement the logic of returning the `allowedValues` of this field based on the value of another field.

In addition, according to [URI Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types%20field/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#uri-parameters), you also cannot add the value of another field as optional parameters to the url for conditional filtering .

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.